# How come the second <li> tag breaks the {} in my code, whilst the first <li> tag and the <a> tags are fine?

Tags: php, html, ajax

How come the second li tag breaks the {} in my code, whilst the first li tag and the a tag are both fine? As soon as I comment out the `echo $RESULT['full_name']);` in the second li tag the code works perfectly and I don't get why.

The error that comes up is the following:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ',' or ';' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ajax.php on line 27

```
<?php

// add name to variable using post

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

    include "db.php";

    $name = $_POST['search'];

    $query = "SELECT full_name FROM Users WHERE full_name LIKE '%$name%' LIMIT 5";

    if ($result = mysqli_query($db, $query)) {
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>1));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>0));
    }

    echo '<ul class = "results">';

    while ($RESULT = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

?>

<li onclick = 'fill("example")'></li>

<li onclick = 'fill("<?php echo $RESULT['full_name']); ?>")'>
<a><?php echo $RESULT['full_name']; ?></a>
</li>



//use name to query similiar names and assign to result variable using mysqli_fetch_array

//based on that reult, loop through all the rows which are simililiar and echo their full name in that list in an li

<?php 

    }

}

?>

</ul>
```

(thanks a ton in advance)

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a dangling closed parenthesis here, right after the closing bracket:

`<?php echo $RESULT['full_name']); ?>`

Should be:

`<?php echo $RESULT['full_name']; ?>`

Comment: Thanks very much man :)  Dumb of me not to see it tho.

Answer (score 0):

On the line 27 you are having an unnecessary ending bracket

Try replacing this

")'>

With this

")'>